# Slow blockchain syncing on TRON Nile Testnet

Tags: cryptocurrency, tron

Trying to sync nile chain.

Starting node with command:
`java -jar /data/FullNode/FullNode.jar --witness -c /data/FullNode/nile_net_config.conf`
using config from <nileex.io>

Syncing is very slow, often stops syncing at all.
Just about 100-1000 blocks per day.
In tron.log I see: P2P_DISCONNECT reason TOO_MANY_PEERS

I tried `/wallet/listnodes` HTTP API command from public nile nodes and put all that 68 IP`s to seed section in config.
When got about 1600000 blocks, syncing stopped again, same errors in log.

Now I downloaded and unpacked backup output-directory and trying to sync to the end of chain but have same problem.
Blocks getting very slow. Sometime, maybe one times in a hour I getting 50-100 blocks.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I used old version of FullNode.jar
Now it`s ok with version 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

> I used old version of FullNode.jar Now it`s ok with version 4.4.1.

That's correct, after bumping version, error is gone, looking at java-tron repository seems like there are several different conditions for throwing TOO_MANY_PEERS one of it below:

```
    @Override
public void run() {
  List<PeerConnection> peerConnectionList = pool.getActivePeers();
  List<PeerConnection> willDisconnectPeerList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (PeerConnection peerConnection : peerConnectionList) {
    NodeStatistics nodeStatistics = peerConnection.getNodeStatistics();
    if (!nodeStatistics.nodeIsHaveDataTransfer()
        && System.currentTimeMillis() - peerConnection.getStartTime() >= CHECK_TIME
        && !peerConnection.isTrustPeer()
        && !nodeStatistics.isPredefined()) {
      //if xxx minutes not have data transfer,disconnect the peer,
      //exclude trust peer and active peer
      willDisconnectPeerList.add(peerConnection);
    }
    nodeStatistics.resetTcpFlow();
  }
  if (!willDisconnectPeerList.isEmpty() && peerConnectionList.size()
      > Args.getInstance().getNodeMaxActiveNodes() * maxConnectNumberFactor) {
    Collections.shuffle(willDisconnectPeerList);
    for (int i = 0; i < willDisconnectPeerList.size() * disconnectNumberFactor; i++) {
      logger.error("{} does not have data transfer, disconnect the peer",
          willDisconnectPeerList.get(i).getInetAddress());
      willDisconnectPeerList.get(i).disconnect(ReasonCode.TOO_MANY_PEERS);
    }
  }
}
```